# Ag grid community Text Filter textMatcher (Text Custom Matcher) doesn't have any affect on filtering

Tags: ag-grid

textMatcher is not marked as "e" but trying to implement it in community version, in order to add some special capabilities to the filtering, doesn't have any affect:
columnDefs = [ {
field: 'country',
filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
filterParams: {
defaultOption: 'contains',
textMatcher: ({ filter, value, filterText }) => {
// return true/false according to some decision
},
},
......

Is it only available in enterprise version or do I need to define something else in order to use it?

Comment: I am also using Community edition. Although I could not make it log a message to the console, I was able to use textMatcher for the default text filter. Depending on the return value api call is made. I am able to call alert() inside and see the result.